# ASP.NET MVC: How to override parent Controller method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have many `Controllers`, and a lot of this `Controllers` share common `Action`. What is the best way to share these common `Actions` to eliminate duplicating the code?

One way I know is to refactor these common `Actions` into parent `abstract Controller`, like so..

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller {

    //handles common help page for all controllers
    public ActionResult Help(string helpTopic) {
        ..open help page..
        return View(page);
    }
}

//now Controller1 and Controller2 has the help page for free!
public class Controller1: BaseController {
}

public class Controller2: BaseController {
}
```

But if I attempt to override the `Help` action within any of the sub controllers like so..

```
//customized help page for Controller1
public class Controller1: BaseController {
    public new ActionResult Help(string helpTopic) {
        .. my own customized help page..
        return View(page);
    }
}
```

I will get error **`The current request for action 'Help' on controller type 'Controller1' is ambiguous between....`**

So how do I override parent controller method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to successfully override a parent controller's method is to mark the method as `virtual` and use the `override` keyword in the child controller method, like so...

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller {

    //handles common help page for all controllers
    public virtual ActionResult Help(string helpTopic) {
        ..open help page..
        return View(page);
    }
}

//Controller1 has a customized help page
public class Controller1: BaseController {
    public override ActionResult Help(string helpTopic) {
        .. my own customized help page..
        return View(page);
    }
}

//Controller2 has help page for free!
public class Controller2: BaseController {
}
```